# How to Deserialize JSON Data using Gson, if no meta-Info available (for ex : type information)

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

There is already data present in S3 Bucket which needs to be processed.

Data Follow this particular Schema

```
{
  "serviceId": "9e148371a96b9054e689d3669998ef54ff11cdd3cad9dfa395e4da4c5a50cbc4",
  "serviceVersion": 2
}
```

POJO Classes

```
abstract class Service {
    String serviceId;
    int serviceVersion;
}

ServiceA extends Service {
    String fieldX;
}

ServiceB extends Service {
}
```

Code

```
USing Gson to desrialize this data

Gson gson = new Gson();
String data = "{\n" +
                "  \"serviceId\": \"9e148371a96b9054e689d3669998ef54ff11cdd3cad9dfa395e4da4c5a50cbc4\",\n" +
                "  \"serviceVersion\": 2\n" +
                "}";
```

Code fails with exception

`Failed to invoke public com.*.transportation.*.Service()()` with no args

How do i deserialize this data ?

Registering CustomType Adapters won't help either, since Data is already deserialized, and no Type information is available.

Only solution i can think of here, is to create customerTypeAdapter and decide the Type of Concrete class on the basis of

```
@Override
    public Service deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
                                       JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

        if (Object.nonNull(jsonObject.get("fieldX") {
         return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement,ServiceA.class);
        }
         jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement,ServiceB.class);
    }
```

Please suggest some the alternative, if this can be solved in a better way?

I have provided this as an example, but the actual object is very large and consists of too many nested interface/abstract classes.

Data is already present in S3/Local Storage and no _type information is present.

Comment: What the heck is fieldX? It's not in your example json...

Comment: it could be present in some of the records corresponding to ServiceA

Comment: If there is no "_type" information, I can't see any other way other than writing some custom code, as youself already considered.

Comment: True, there is no other an alternative or a way than having something like `_type`. If `fieldX` is optional, you can't really distinguish between `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. I don't think it's resolvable in principle.